# Can't Debug on physical Device (switches to Virtual device)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to debug(run) an Xamarin Application on a Android device. Every time i try to run the application on the device the target device switches back to the virtual Android_accelerated device. It doesn't matter what project, USB cable or phone i use.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow. You need to describe your environment more carefully. Are you running on a Mac, Windows? Did you check if your device appears running `adb devices`, does it appear in the list of devices in Visual Studio? Are your tools up to date?

Comment: Oh yes ofcourse.

im running a mac on the latest version on macos. 

All the tools are up to date including the newest version of Visual Studio. The android phone does appear in the device list. But when i click on it, it selects automatically the virtual device again

Comment: Which device is it? And I assume you have enabled ADB USB debugging on it.

Comment: Lg nexus 5, but is doesnt work on any android device. Ios devices are working perfect. Yes usb debugging is enabled